# what is a non-destructive version of set in lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I would  like to be able to say (defvar x y) and have it bind to the symbol bound to x instead of x, but defvar will only bind it to the symbol x, which is too bad.  How can I do this without defaulting to adding it a a property of the symbol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `symbol-value` accessor:

```
CL-USER> (defvar *sym* 'abc)
*SYM*
CL-USER> (setf (symbol-value *sym*) 100)
100
CL-USER> abc    ;non-ANSI-portable, since ABC is undeclared
100
```

Note that this sets the symbol's *[value cell](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_v.htm#value_cell)*, which is the same as its dynamic binding, so in order to portably access it, you either need to use `symbol-value` all the time or (either locally or globally) declare the variable `special`.  You can do this locally like this:

```
CL-USER> (locally (declare (special abc))
           (+ abc 3))
103
```

or globally by using `defvar` (which isn't recommended for non-earmuffed symbols):

```
CL-USER> (defvar abc)
ABC
```

(I know of no CL implementation that actually requires this, though. You're usually safe assuming that undeclared variables are assumed special by default.)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Matthias' answer:

You could also use [`set`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_set.htm)

```
T1> (defparameter *symbol* 'foo)
*SYMBOL*
T1> (set *symbol* 100)
100
```

since `(set symbol value) ==  (setf (symbol-value symbol) value)`, i.e. in contrast to `setq` and `setf`, `set` evaluates its first argument. (`setq` could be read as "set quoted") `set` is marked deprecated in the Hyperspec, but since I don't really expect the next CL standard anytime soon, it should be safe to use.

---

Also, I don't think you'd have to use `symbol-value` or any special declarations in order to portably access it -- At least for all practical purposes. (While one could maybe argue that, technically, since one cannot rely on the modified symbol even being locally special, maybe the variable wouldn't be evaluated via `symbol-value`, but see the referenced Naggum post below, and Matthias' last sentence.)

It is true, that `setq`, `setf`, `set` et al. are only guaranteed to modify bindings for conforming implementations. When used at toplevel, the `symbol-value` will be modified, but you can't rely on any global special declaration (or anything else) taking place (cf. [Naggum](http://www.xach.com/naggum/articles/3160842339136874@naggum.no.html)). But usually, implementations will at least make evaluating the new variable use the `symbol-value` slot. This doesn't mean that one has to use `symbol-value` or local/global special declarations in order to access the `symbol-value`, but it *does* mean, that a *new* binding of the same symbol won't be automatically special, as it would be the case with variables introduced via `defparameter` and friends.

So, while usually, with global special variables:

```
T1> (let ((*symbol* 'bar))
      (symbol-value '*symbol*))
BAR
```

A *new* binding to a *non* global special will itself not be special:

```
T1> (let ((foo 101))       ; this new binding is lexical
      (symbol-value 'foo)) ; so symbol-value refers to the outer special
100
T1> (let ((foo 101))
      foo)                 ; evaluation of foo's new lexical binding
101                        ; doesn't look at the `symbol-value`. lexical
                           ; bindings are mere addresses at runtime.
```

And that's also where the local special declaration could be used in order to reference the outer, (not globally) special binding of `foo`:

```
T1> (let ((foo 101))
      foo)              ; our new lexical binding
101
T1> (let ((foo 101))
      (locally (declare (special foo))
        foo))           ; the outer special binding
100
T1> (let ((foo 101))
      (setq foo 102)    ; modify the new lexical binding
      foo)
102
T1> foo                 ; doesn't modify the outer special binding
100
T1> (let ((foo 101))
      (locally (declare (special foo))
        (setq foo 102)  ; modify the outer special binding
        foo))
102
T1> foo
102
```

As far as I understand, the undefined part, or at least the one where you should expect portability problems, is whether such toplevel modifications might declare something (globally) special or not. The behavior I would *expect* is what I have shown here, but if the variable will be declared globally special or not (or maybe even introduce a toplevel lexical variable?) as long as it is at least made locally special, one won't need local declarations or `symbol-value` to access it.

Also, you should consider if you really need what you've asked for. It's likely that what you want to do could be solved in a more idiomatic (at least for modern Lispers) way, and relying on undefined behavior would not be considered good style by most for anything but REPL use.

Comment: CMU CL _does_ in fact globally declare a variable created by `setq` special.  (This is, of course, not true for `(setf symbol-value)`.  Maybe you meant that; I just wanted to clarify.)

Comment: Matthias: I meant, that I'd *expect* a toplevel `setq` either to be globally special or locally at toplevel (I think the latter is more common). In both cases, one wouldn't have to use `symbol-value`. But (and that's how I understand your answer) not even *that* is guaranteed, so theoretically, one must use `symbol-value` to be absolutely portable. (But thats what I *wouldn't* expect.) Maybe the second part of my answer isn't as clear as it could be, but the examples might still be helpful. The main point was that one can use `set`, and usually, there's no need for `symbol-value`.

Comment: (The "usually, there's no need for `symbol-value`" refers to this question only. Of course there are situations where it is used.)

Comment: I was talking about these sentences: “`setq`, `setf`, `set` et al. only modify bindings.  When used at toplevel, the `symbol-value` will be modified, but no global special declaration takes place.”  I agree with everything else. :)